# .htaccess mod rewrite to redirect query string to a path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've recently updated my website to use:

```
www.website.com/path/123456
```

instead of:

```
www.website.com/path/file.php?id=123456
```

In order to not break legacy links/bookmarks, I'd like to redirect the old query strings to the new paths.

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^path/file.php?id=?$ /path/$1 [L,R]
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/.* /path/$1 [R]
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /path/$1 [R]
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/file.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /path/$1 [R]
```

and a few variations, but with no luck. How do I need to set up my .htaccess to perform this redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is your regex isn't capturing the parameter, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^path/file.php?id=(.*)$ /path/$1 [L,R]
```

In a regular expression use parenthesis to capture parts of the string you want to reference later, like with `$1`.  The `.*` will match anything.  So if you want to capture just digits, for example, you could change this to `(\d+)`.

Comment: This did not work for me, nothing happened I just visited the link like normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /path/file\.php\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /path/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^path/(\d+)/?$ path/file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This did not work for me, nothing happened I just visited the link like normal.

Comment: The .htaccess is located at the root (above `/path/`). There are other rules, but I've tried rearranging and removing others to make it work.

Comment: `/path/` does not have its own .htaccess, there is only one at the root of the application. It does however have more rules. When removing all rules, and replacing the file with what you have given me I get a 404 page with `The requested URL /path/file.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: ok same rule works fine in my apache with exact same URL. Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: I do get a 500, and other rules do work when they're in the file.

Comment: As I said this exact rule on my Apache redirects `http://localhost/path/file.php?id=123456 to http://localhost/path/123456`